# THREEJS: add hole to rendered Shape

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to inject hole to the shape that is already added to the scene, but some thing going wrong...
so in details: the shape

```
        var well,
            vertices = [],
            wellShape,
            wellMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: this.params.wellsColor});

            vertices.push(new THREE.Vector2(0,3000));
            vertices.push(new THREE.Vector2(4000,3000));
            vertices.push(new THREE.Vector2(4000,0));
            vertices.push(new THREE.Vector2(0,0));

            wellShape = new THREE.Shape(vertices);

            well = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.ShapeGeometry(wellShape), wellMaterial);

    scene.add(well);

    well.geometry.dynamic = true;

    var hole = [
            new THREE.Vector3(300,300,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(1000,300,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(1000,1000,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(300,1000,0)
        ];

        well.geometry.vertices = well.geometry.vertices.concat(hole);
        well.geometry.faces = [];

var triangles = THREE.Shape.Utils.triangulateShape ( well.geometry.vertices, hole );

    for( var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++ ){

        well.geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( triangles[i][0], triangles[i][1], triangles[i][2] ));
        well.geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][i] = THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.WorldUVGenerator.generateTopUV(well.geometry, triangles[i][0], triangles[i][1], triangles[i][2]);

}
```

but as result i got something strange: in console output "Infinite Loop! Holes left:4, Probably Hole outside Shape!" and on desktop i got https://yadi.sk/i/WHRzH7c2jnaRm
could someone tell me what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after few days play around I found what is wrong:
1. **THREE.Shape.Utils.triangulateShape** expect vertices and holes to be parts of same shape.
2. hole should be not the array of points but array of path.
3. vertices should be concated after triangulation.
so correct result is:

```
....
var holePoints = [
            new THREE.Vector3(300,300,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(1000,300,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(1000,1000,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(300,1000,0)
        ],
hole = new THREE.Path();
hole.fromPoints(holePoints);

var shape = new THREE.Shape(well.geometry.vertices);
shape.holes = [hole];
var points = shape.extractPoints();
well.geometry.faces = [];

var triangles = THREE.Shape.Utils.triangulateShape ( points.vertices, points.holes );
....
```

Hope someone will find this info helpful.