# creating holes in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is actually taken from [THREEJS: add hole to rendered Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176150/threejs-add-hole-to-rendered-shape) . But it's still not working.

The error is

> three.js:34206 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined

```
var plane, vertices = [], planeShape;
        var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xC0C0C0});

        vertices.push(
            new THREE.Vector3(-room_width/2,room_depth/2,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(room_width/2,room_depth/2,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(room_width/2,-room_depth/2,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(-room_width/2,-room_depth/2,0)
        );

        planeShape = new THREE.Shape(vertices);

        plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.ShapeGeometry(planeShape), planeMaterial);

        scene.add(plane);

        var holes = [
            new THREE.Vector3(-room_width/4,room_depth/4,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(room_width/4,room_depth/4,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(room_width/4,-room_depth/4,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(-room_width/4,-room_depth/4,0)
        ],

        hole = new THREE.Path();
        hole.fromPoints(holes);

        var shape = new THREE.Shape(plane.geometry.vertices);
        shape.holes = [hole];
        var points = shape.extractPoints();

        plane.geometry.faces = [];

        var triangles = THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape ( points.vertices, points.holes );

        for( var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++ ){
            plane.geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( triangles[i][0], triangles[i][1], triangles[i][2] ));
        }
```

edit::: ANS

```
        var plane, vertices = [], planeShape;
        var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xC0C0C0});

        vertices.push(
            new THREE.Vector3(-150,-150,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(150,-150,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(150,150,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(-150,150,0)
        );

        planeShape = new THREE.Shape(vertices);

        plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.ShapeGeometry(planeShape), planeMaterial);

        scene.add(plane);

        var holes = [
            new THREE.Vector3(-75,-75,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(75,-75,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(75,75,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(-75,75,0)
        ],

        hole = new THREE.Path();
        hole.fromPoints(holes);

        var shape = new THREE.Shape(plane.geometry.vertices);
        shape.holes = [hole];
        var points = shape.extractPoints();

        plane.geometry.faces = [];

        var triangles = THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape ( points.shape, points.holes );

        plane.geometry.vertices.push(
            new THREE.Vector3(-75,-75,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(75,-75,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(75,75,0),
            new THREE.Vector3(-75,75,0)
        );
        for( var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++ ){
            plane.geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( triangles[i][0], triangles[i][1], triangles[i][2] ));
        }
```

Comment: please post a runnable example.hard test your code

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your comment

Comment: you should provide complete minimal code example.your code has lot of errors because it's just half of code.if i want to test your code i have to add three.js,declare all undeclared variable..fix all errors one by one.that's why you didn't get any answers yet.if you really expect an answer you have to spend some time to ask a good question

Comment: I just need to add the holes also to the vertices of the plane. By the way thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling onto this, there is now a much simpler way to work with holes compared to the old "THREE.ShapeUtils.triangulateShape" and constructing the triangles yourself.

```
//vertices is the main shape/contour/exterior, a "ring" as a list of THREE.Vector2 instances
//holes is a list of THREE.Path instances, created from THREE.Vector2
//If you pass THREE.Vector3 then the Z property is ignored.

var shape = new THREE.Shape(vertices);
shape.holes = holes;

var geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( shape );

...
```